# Can a rolling wheel create a side force without first rotating on a vertical axis at its contact patch?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics, wheels, car, rolling

There is something wrong with the way we describe how a cornering vehicle wheel creates a cornering force. I think a rolling wheel must first rotate on a vertical axis to then create the cornering force. This is fundamentally different than what we think about cornering wheels. Can anyone else see this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88747/discussion-on-question-by-matt-zusy-the-physics-of-a-cornering-wheel-and-our-err).

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is missing substantial information regarding statics and equilibrium. Think for a minute:

The instantaneous forces acting in the wheel system are radial velocity, momentum, inertia, kinetic energy and friction. Above all there is also gravity. When the wheel changes direction, its centroid remains constant but its centre of gravity changes. It is possible for a body in motion to have its centre of gravity outside itself. This occurs because of a constant resistance force applied to the control arm which exceeds the losing radial velocity gyroscopic forces. In addition there is the moment of inertia imbalance that is corrected by asked force through the control arm. The axle or more correctly, constant velocity joint (cvj), transmits force to the issuing wheel which also provides resistance to direction change observing by steering control arm. This is why wheel bearings are often the conical thrust type or specially designed ball race type instead of rod type bearings.

The lateral forces are the result of radial inertia change with an equal and opposite force in the directing of steering. Newton's third law of motion...

Comment: perpetual motion does not exist, but perpetual discussion does - just a heads up...

Comment: Thanks Rhodie. I left out the obvious because there is only so much I can fit. The answer is not in the details. It is in the fundamental rules established by Newton. I purposely did not focus on CoG location because we only need to know that when the mass velocity is parallel to the travel direction of the wheel you have no cornering/lateral force. When the mass velocity and wheel travel direction are different directions there IS a force. I show how to cause this force in two examples. But in the steady state turn, we mistakenly believe that a wheel cornering force occurs without a cause.

Comment: Now, if we say the force is a centripetal force I say that it can’t be because a wheel is limited to straight path travel and centripetal force only occurs to bodies experiencing angular motion. We observe what we believe is angular motion, but this is no different than saying I experience a centripetal force when my foot pushes me laterally when I’m walking. If I do it enough times I am traveling a circular path and rotating around a center point. Not the case. Laws of motion are very specific for a reason.

Comment: Consider a wheel with its plane perpendicular to the plane of the surface it rolls along. From a stop we roll it forward. ANY motion forward is linear motion. There is no change in direction until the wheel rotates around a vertical axis. When does the cornering force occur? AFTER the vertical axis rotation. Cause and effect.

Comment: Sure but equilibrium is maintained due to the continued applied force that induces change. The wheel is part of a system not the system itself. Newton's second law of motion is in play

Comment: Does a wheel in motion ONLY roll straight? If not then what would make it roll along a circular/curved path?

Comment: The wheel is part of the system, but the wheel has its own physical reality that doesn’t change no matter what system it plays a roll in.  First examine what a wheel does without being connected to another wheel by a vehicle frame. It doesn’t magically inherit new properties because it’s now on a car. If the only way to change the direction of a wheel by its self is to rotate it on a vertical axis then the car system MUST do the exact same thing. See 40 seconds into this video. All car wheels must first pivot to change direction. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvTBDdW-T-Q

Comment: @MattZusyThe dynamic behaviour of a wheel is really complicated since its not a cylinder, but rather elastic.

Comment: @jooja But the wheel’s rolling motion is the same. If it’s about the wheel elasticity then what amount of elasticity of the cylinder will make it have the characteristics of the wheel where it no longer needs to rotate on a vertical axis to turn? There are important details and elasticity is one, but this is about geometry and the similar charastics.

Comment: To make a wheel change direction systemically you need to change its centre of gravity towards the direction in which you want it to tend towards. Another way is to dynamically change its circumferential diameter.